# PHP Notice: Undefined index: in a line

Tags: php, debugging, syntax-error

I know a lot of people have asked this question but mine is not working with:

```
if(isset($instance['threadnumbers'] == "")){ $instance['threadnumbers'] == "" }
```

It shows a debugging errors on:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: threadnumbers in /home/content/59/12158859/html/development/wp-content/plugins/dpt/disqus-ptw.php on line 27

And that area is below:

```
if ($instance['threadnumbers'] == NULL) {
    $instance['threadnumbers'] = "5";
}
```

How to fix it? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a cut and paste error. You are trying to assign a value using a comparison operator. `==` should be `=`.

You also are using `isset()` on an assignment.

```
if(isset($instance['threadnumbers'])){ $instance['threadnumbers'] == "" }
```

should be

```
if(!isset($instance['threadnumbers']) || empty($instance['threadnumbers'])) { 
    $instance['threadnumbers'] = ""; 
}
```

Comment: This is the first time I've seen a reversal of the usual assignment as comparison issue.

Comment: Yep and just in case there's anything else below that, `$instance['threadnumbers'] = "";` <=

Comment: This will not solve the error. Look at my answer below. The problem is that `isset` returns a boolean. A boolean loose compared with an empty string can be true when the boolean is `false`. So when it's not set, it will still get into the if and execute the code between brackets.

Comment: @BennoZeeman Correct. I have updated my answer with the other issue. +1 for seeing that quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
if(isset($instance['threadnumbers'] == "")){ $instance['threadnumbers'] == "" }
```

With

```
if(isset($instance['threadnumbers'])){ $instance['threadnumbers'] = "" }
```

`isset` will return `true` or `false`. When you loose compare it (`==`), `false` will equal `""`.

Also, `$instance['threadnumbers'] == ""` should be `$instance['threadnumbers'] = ""`, because you want to assign an empty string to the variable.